# Android image editor which visually and functionally integrates with Google Camera app

Tags: android, image-processing, image-editor

I'm looking for a free, preferably open source Android image editor which supports basic functions such as cropping, resizing and rotating. I use an AOSP device with a Google Camera app so I would like it to visually and functionally integrate with it meaning "the same principle of using the app" on a subjective level - not that it needs to interface with the Google Camera app directly (the editor file association is handled by the Android itself). The support for batch processing would be another plus, but it is not strictly necessary. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I cannot argue for the one or other as I'm not using any on Android (I do my photo editing on Linux) – but be welcome to take a look at my [collection of photo editing apps for Android](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit), which might narrow down your search a bit at least. Feel free to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if you found a fitting app :)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean it should feel like you are in the same app? In particular, you want to avoid having to click "Share"?

Comment: There is no need to click Share as the editor file association is handled by the Android itself. When you click the "pen" icon meaning "edit image" in Google Camera, the (currently empty in my case) Android "Open with" menu pops out. As @NicolasRaoul pointed out, it should feel like you are in a **similar**, not necessary the same, app.

Comment: So, you are OK with using the "Open with" button every time?

Comment: No, because it is possible to set "always" the second time image is edited and from that point on I consider the two applications "integrated".

Answer (score 0):

After extensive search I've found an acceptable solution and that is the AOSP Gallery app ported from Android 4.4 (which also includes basic image editing and filtering options). It can be found in the Play Store under the name [Galery KK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.galleryics).